# Mouse Click detection only on opaque areas of movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3, mouseevent, collision-detection

I have movieclips (which in turn have more than 1 movieclips in them ). My requirement is to add a `MouseEvent.CLICK` event to the parent movieclip. So that an event (`MouseEvent.CLICK`) is dispatched by flash only if the visually opaque (alpha = 100 %) area has been clicked, otherwise , ignore.

The workaround I do as of now is to create an `alpha = 0.05` circle which follows the mousecursor in `Event.ENTER_FRAME` and do a hittest followed by a `PixelPerfectCollisionDetection` (courtesy one gr8 guy I admire on google code :) )

In short,
I need to know If I can make flash dispatch a MouseEvent only when clicked on a visually opaque area of the movieclip and **NOT** `anywhere in the bounding box region.`

Thanks,

Vishnu Ajit

Comment: Convert the clicked object to BitmapData and then use [`getPixel32()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#getPixel32()) to work out the ARGB value of where you're clicking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this solution. But It's not perfect at all, cause you create everytime a new `bitmapData` object of your `MovieClip`:

```
myButton.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, clickFunction);

private function clickFunction(e:MouseEvent) {
    if(pixelIsVisible(e.currentTarget, e.currentTarget.mouseX, e.currentTarget.mouseY)) {
        //DoSomething
    }
}   

private function pixelIsVisible(target:*, xPos:int, yPos:int):Boolean {
    var bmp:BitmapData = new BitmapData( target.width, target.height, false );
    bmp.draw( target as MovieClip );
    var pixelValue = bmp.getPixel( xPos, yPos);

    //Dispose bitmapData to free memory
    bmp.dispose();

    var alphaValue:uint = pixelValue >> 24 & 0xFF;
    //alphaValue is from 0 to 255
    if(alphaValue >= 255) return true;
    else false;
}
```

Comment: Damnit.. I just finished coding essentially the same thing :|

Comment: Though you might want to mention that this will only work if the graphics in the MovieClip/Sprite are at 0,0 ;)

Comment: Tha graphic is the MovieClip itself. So when the clicked Area has no image/shape/anything it gives back false. So it should be right?

Comment: Yeah but if the contents of the MovieClip aren't at 0,0 then the results will be off (because the BitmapData will be pulled from 0,0). Give it a try.